# When is a website considered "static" or "dynamic"

Tags: naming-conventions

I have created a site, which parses XML files and display its content on the appropriate page. Is my site a dynamic web page or static web page?

How do dynamic and static web pages differ?

I feel it's dynamic, because I parse the content from xml files; initially i don't have any content in my main page..

What do you think about this, please explain it..

Answer (score 4):

I would describe your pages as dynamic. "Static" usually means that the file sitting on the web server is delivered as-is to the user; since you're assembling the pages from data files, I'd call them dynamic even if you're not building in any dynamically-changing data.

I don't think this is a hard and fast definition though. If someone feels the page is static because it's assembled from static pages, that's another way to look at it.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually an interesting question..

I would have said it's a dynamic website, as the content is generated programmatically.. but if the XML files do not change, it's no less "static" than straight HTML files served though Apache.

Say you have a site that is regular HTML files - it would be considered a static web-page; but if you take those HTML files, store them in a database, and have a simple page that allows `/view.php?page=index` - does that make it a dynamic site?

I would say no, it's just a static site served through a database, or XML files (instead of a file-system).

Basically: if the content changes without you manually editing those XML files, I would say it's a dynamic site. If it does change, then I would say it's a static site.

Answer (score 1):

Static web pages would be plain HTML content that are delivered. If you are processing any type of XML files at the server side and generating content accordingly, this is a dynamic page. Static pages change content when the page is actually edited & modified.

First result on Google if you had searched for it explains it. http://websiteowner.info/articles/pages/pagetypes.asp

Also, stating that static websites are not updated regularly is not correct. The web and HTML was around even before we started writing stuff in Perl & PHP. There are/were sites that had heavy traffic and were being modified manually.

Answer (score 1):

a simple way to distinguish between static and dynamic:

Static: straight HTML files

Dynamic: HTML is generated through server-side code and a data store(XML, database, etc.)

Comment: What if those straight HTML files are stored in a database? Does the data coming from a database mean it's a dynamic website, even if the content is only ever manually edited?

Comment: That's an interesting question. It seemed like a simple question so I provided a simple answer. I guess what you are suggesting could be up for debate. If there is code deciding what to display from the database, I would call it dynamic since they still aren't using plain HTML alone.

Answer (score 1):

[KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) - *Dynamic pages change **without changing the page itself**.*

Your pages are dynamic, because once deployed the content can be changed without changing the page's HTML.

Any content that is fixed and always renders the same is considered Static.